# PHP: setting a private var to return value of a private method is not working

Tags: php, class, methods, return, private

I have a private variable *$user_url* which I initialize to "".
So I set it in a public function like: `$this->user_url = $this->generate_user_url();`
However it always returns null, even though I know it isn't.
Please help!!!!!!!

```
 private $user_url;
 private $user_url_extension = '';


public function create_user(){
$this->user_url = $this->generate_user_url();

// here i echo $this->user_url; output is null

$my_url = $this->generate_user_url();
// echoing $my_url does work

}



private function generate_user_url(){
        preg_match('/\@(.*?)\./s', $this->email, $school_identifier); 
        $first_character_first_name = mb_substr($this->first_name, 0, 1);
        $temp_user_url = $first_character_first_name.$this->last_name.'@'.$school_identifier[1].$this->user_url_extension;
        $stm = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT user_url from hm_users WHERE user_url=:user_url');
        $stm->bindParam(':user_url', $temp_user_url);
        $stm->execute();
        $res = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        echo '.....................................';
            var_dump($res);
            echo '.....................................';
            echo '.....................................';
            var_dump($temp_user_url);
            echo '.....................................';
        if(!$res){
            echo '.....................................url is being returned';
            var_dump($temp_user_url);
            echo '.....................................';
            return $temp_user_url;
        }
        else{
            $this->user_url_extension = strval(rand(1, 999));
            $this->generate_user_url();
        }


      }


//everything inside private function is as expected, temp_url is set and would apear to return as that part of code is reached.
// if any one can help, please do. Thank you in advance.
```

I've tried debugging everywhere prior to asking here

Comment: very strange if i set $this->user_url = $my_url; it works, but that doesnt answer my why question. and it doesnt seam right to do so.

Comment: Your `generate_user_url()` method, when `!$res` is FALSE, doesn't return anything. No matter how you look at it, that's not right. I think you meant to write: `return $this->generate_user_url();`.

Comment: Calling a function that itself returns data does not make the function that calls it return anything. This also applies to functions that call themselves recursively.

Comment: Hi Sammitch, can you elaborate just a bit please? i found that hard to understand. it calls itself until its able to generate a temp_user_url hat isnt in the database, when it is able to it returns the value. it works fine when a regular var is set to it. but please if you would, explain.

Comment: you guys are both awesome, with both comments in conjunction, i understand the problem. thanks so much you guys!!!